# Codeigniter query builder disable quotes

Tags: codeigniter, builder

I am using Query builder on CodeIgniter 3. with Oracle DB.
I cannot create normal query. My query is:

```
$CI->db->query('c.*',false);
$CI->db->from('COUNTRIES c',false);
$CI->db->join('FILIALS as f','f.country_id=c.country_id',false);
$CI->db->where('f.FILIAL_ID',$id,false);
$query=$CI->db->get();
return $query->result('Country')[0];
```

This gives me a query

```
SELECT c.* FROM "COUNTRIES" "c" JOIN "FILIALS" as "f" ON "f"."country_id"="c"."country_id" WHERE f.FILIAL_ID = 7
```

But this query does not work, complaining that query is not correct. In Sqlplus the same problem.
But if I manually run in sqlplus,removing "as", and quotes in table fields and table names, it works normal.
This is my working query:

```
SELECT c.* FROM "COUNTRIES" c JOIN "FILIALS"  f ON f.country_id=c.country_id WHERE f.FILIAL_ID = 7
```

How can I tell Query Builder, remove "as", and quotataion marks in query.

Answer (score 1):

Try This Query :

```
$this->db->select('c.*',false);
$this->db->from('COUNTRIES c',false);
$this->db->join('FILIALS as f','f.country_id=c.country_id',false);
$this->db->where('f.FILIAL_ID',$id,false);
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result();
```

Comment: It created the following query. No change in resulted query.          SELECT c.* FROM "COUNTRIES" "c" JOIN "FILIALS" as "f" ON "f"."country_id"="c"."country_id" WHERE f.FILIAL_ID = 7  .   The result is same.

Answer (score 0):

Remove AS from join

I thik its done.

```
$this->db->select('c.*',false);
$this->db->from('COUNTRIES c',false);
$this->db->join('FILIALS f','f.country_id=c.country_id',false);
$this->db->where('f.FILIAL_ID',$id,false);
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result();
```